# How to configure google fonts locally for prestashop

Tags: prestashop

I have downloaded google fonts and uploaded it to webserver where prestashop installed. Now how I can embed google font to prestashop. I could see below codes

its taking from internet. I want all fonts should work without internet.

Comment: <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:600' rel='stylesheet'>

Answer (score 0):

To add fonts to your template (for Prestashop 1.7.x)

Open and edit your HTML :

```
themes/your_theme/templates/_partials/head.tpl
```

Add:

```
<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:600' rel='stylesheet'>
```

Open and edit your CSS :

```
themes/your_theme/assets/theme.css
```

Add this rule to call your font:

```
font-family: 'Open Sans', serif!important;
```

Example, to change font of H1 :

```
h1 {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', serif!important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can download the font files to your computer and upload them to **themes/your_theme/assets/css** directory( you may create **fonts** subfolder or upload directly to css folder).

Than open **themes/your_theme/assets/css/custom.css** file and use **@font-face**:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  src: url("/fonts/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.woff2") format("woff2"),
       url("/fonts/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.woff") format("woff");
}
```

More details:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face

Note, that is better to convert fonts into ttf and otf as well, so each browser can select the suitable format. Use any free font converter in the web.

After that you can use font-family rules in your css code.

Comment: thank you. is this override the current codes from fonts.googleapis.com?

Comment: This code uses the font that you downloaded to your server/localhost rather than Google CDN.